Error while reencoding and combining 3 mp4 files with ffmpeg
I am using the ffmpeg command given in top answer on this below page to join 3 mp4 videos
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg
It says to use that long command in case video parameters are different. Mine are. First video and last video have same scale etc (1280x720), but middle video in my case has a different scale (144p). When I use that command, I get an error and the command fails.
What should I do to fix this?
Below is the ffmpeg command and the error I get:
ffmpeg.exe -i z1.mp4 -i ef.mp4 -i z2.mp4-filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [vv] [aa]" -map "[vv]" -map "[aa]" -y z.mp4

ffmpeg version N-83280-gcba4f0e Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --e
nable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --
enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv
--enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-li
bfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug -
-enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enabl
e-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-li
bsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolam
e --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
 --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable
-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --ena
ble-zlib
  libavutil      55. 45.100 / 55. 45.100
  libavcodec     57. 75.100 / 57. 75.100
  libavformat    57. 65.100 / 57. 65.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 71.100 /  6. 71.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:\wamp64\www\editAudioVid\pro\12345678
9-99\z1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.65.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1146 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720
[SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1005 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 12
7 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:\wamp64\www\editAudioVid\pro\12345678
9-99\ef.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.23.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 211 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte1
70m/bt470bg/bt709), 256x144 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 t
bn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      encoder         : Lavc60.41.100 libx264
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt
p, 139 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:\wamp64\www\editAudioVid\pro\12345678
9-99\z2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.65.100
  Duration: 00:00:28.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1218 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720
[SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1067 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #2:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 14
3 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0353cfa0] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 256x144, SAR 1:1
) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1280x720, SAR 1:
1)
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0353cfa0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_0
Error configuring complex filters.
Invalid argument


scale before concat → ffmpeg -i z1.mp4 -i ef.mp4 -i z2.mp4 -filter_complex " [1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1[v1]; [0:v][0:a] [v1][1:a] [2:v][2:a] concat=3:1:1 " -y z.mp4

Hi, I was under the impression that this demuxer command will match all parameters of  later inputs with the first input and will then reencode to make an output video. Is there a way to do this automatically, without me having to manually set the scale and fps and sar/dar etc etc values? There are so many videos I need to do this for, each have different scale/fps/sar/dar etc etc. I'll go mad if I have to figure all these parameters manually for each video I want to fix... Any command where ffmpeg automatically matches the parameters with the very first input will be suitable for my purpose.

try this variant with ffmpeg v7 → ffmpeg -i z1.mp4 -i ef.mp4 -i z2.mp4 -filter_complex " [1:v][0:v]scale=rw:rh:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, setsar=1, pad='max(iw,ih*16/9)':'max(iw*9/16,ih)':-1:-1[v1]; [0:v][0:a] [v1][1:a] [2:v][2:a] concat=3:1:1 " -y z.mp4

Hi, This was getting too confusing for me, plus same video will need to be made again and again "during processing". So I decided to make different ef.mp4 files "beforehand" which can be joined with matching z1.mp4 and z2.mp4 files later on while processing. My problem now is that I am not able to get the ef.mp4 files to match the iw/ih/sar/dar/fps etc in the new reencoded ef.mp4 file. I have started a different question for the same, could you please please please help there? https://superuser.com/questions/1848325/reencoded-video-with-ffmpeg-is-not-matching-input-sar-dar-provided
