Reencoded video with ffmpeg is not matching input sar,dar provided
I am trying to reencode a video (temp.mp4) to a certain width/height, with particular sar/dar/fps to match it with another mp4 file which I need to join with temp.mp4 file.
I want to achieve these results:
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1067 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)

instead, I am getting this result:
Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 81:16 DAR 9:1], 674 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)

Here is my ffmpeg command:
ffmpeg.exe -i temp.mp4 -c:a libmp3lame -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,setsar=r=1:max=1,setdar=r=16:max=9" -r 25 -y ef.mp4

This is output from ffmpeg when above command is run
ffmpeg version N-83280-gcba4f0e Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --e
nable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --
enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv
--enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-li
bfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug -
-enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enabl
e-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-li
bsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolam
e --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
 --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable
-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --ena
ble-zlib
  libavutil      55. 45.100 / 55. 45.100
  libavcodec     57. 75.100 / 57. 75.100
  libavformat    57. 65.100 / 57. 65.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 71.100 /  6. 71.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:\wamp64\www\editAudioVid\pro\12345678
9-99\temp.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.23.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 211 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte1
70m/bt470bg/bt709), 256x144 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 t
bn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      encoder         : Lavc60.41.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt
p, 139 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
[libx264 @ 03094f20] using SAR=81/16
[libx264 @ 03094f20] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 03094f20] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 03094f20] 264 - core 148 r2744 b97ae06 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Cop
yleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deb
lock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 m
e_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chro
ma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 i
nterlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenec
ut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=
0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'D:\wamp64\www\editAudioVid\pro\123456789-99\ef.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.65.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1
280x720 [SAR 81:16 DAR 9:1], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      encoder         : Lavc57.75.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) (i[0][0][0] / 0x0069), 44100 Hz, s
tereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      encoder         : Lavc57.75.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Past duration 0.666664 too large
Past duration 0.833321 too large
frame=   46 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.77 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   60 fps= 43 q=28.0 size=      64kB time=00:00:02.35 bitrate= 221.9kbits/
frame=   74 fps= 39 q=28.0 size=     120kB time=00:00:02.92 bitrate= 335.5kbits/
frame=   87 fps= 36 q=28.0 size=     166kB time=00:00:03.42 bitrate= 396.8kbits/
frame=  103 fps= 35 q=28.0 size=     213kB time=00:00:04.07 bitrate= 427.2kbits/
frame=  118 fps= 34 q=28.0 size=     253kB time=00:00:04.70 bitrate= 441.4kbits/
frame=  127 fps= 23 q=-1.0 Lsize=     503kB time=00:00:05.01 bitrate= 821.1kbits
/s dup=0 drop=23 speed=0.917x
video:418kB audio:79kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
overhead: 1.175507%
[libx264 @ 03094f20] frame I:1     Avg QP:16.84  size: 13183
[libx264 @ 03094f20] frame P:44    Avg QP:18.53  size:  6421
[libx264 @ 03094f20] frame B:82    Avg QP:22.91  size:  1608
[libx264 @ 03094f20] consecutive B-frames:  7.1% 15.7% 14.2% 63.0%
[libx264 @ 03094f20] mb I  I16..4: 49.0% 46.5%  4.6%
[libx264 @ 03094f20] mb P  I16..4:  3.3%  9.3%  0.3%  P16..4: 20.4%  4.2%  1.7%
 0.0%  0.0%    skip:60.9%
[libx264 @ 03094f20] mb B  I16..4:  0.3%  0.6%  0.0%  B16..8: 15.2%  0.9%  0.1%
 direct: 0.9%  skip:82.0%  L0:44.7% L1:53.6% BI: 1.7%
[libx264 @ 03094f20] 8x8 transform intra:68.2% inter:94.8%
[libx264 @ 03094f20] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 35.3% 47.5% 16.1% inter: 3.1% 7.7%
 0.2%
[libx264 @ 03094f20] i16 v,h,dc,p: 27% 25%  5% 44%
[libx264 @ 03094f20] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 20% 23%  3%  6%  6%  5%
 4%  4%
[libx264 @ 03094f20] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 36% 19% 13%  3%  9%  8%  6%
 4%  2%
[libx264 @ 03094f20] i8c dc,h,v,p: 49% 18% 20% 13%
[libx264 @ 03094f20] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 03094f20] ref P L0: 70.9%  7.5% 16.7%  4.9%
[libx264 @ 03094f20] ref B L0: 81.5% 15.8%  2.6%
[libx264 @ 03094f20] ref B L1: 96.7%  3.3%
[libx264 @ 03094f20] kb/s:673.28


Your video input is 256x144 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9]. For that, you just need -vf "scale=1280:720".
The scale filter will adjust the output so as to keep the input DAR, so unless you've cropped or padded the input before scaling, you don't need to do anything.

Hi @Gyan there are more videos I need to reencode which do not have same SAR/DAR/FPS as needed output. Could you please give me the full command with setsar/setdar so that different SAR/DAR etc will also match? This is input video for example:   Stream #0:00x1: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 480x368 [SAR 1:1 DAR 30:23], 650 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn (default)

@SmithKumar, in this case (DAR 30:23), you can pad black bars → ffmpeg -i 480x368.mp4 -vf " scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, pad='max(iw,ih*16/9)':'max(iw*9/16,ih)':-1:-1, setsar=1 " -r 25 ef.mp4 -y

Thanks, this is working now.
